# Access instance variable inside rspec around hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have a pretty straightforward rspec hook question- Basically I'd like to do this:

```
before { @stub =  double(expires_at: 1.day.from_now) }

describe 'after expiration' do
  around do |example|
    travel_to(@stub.expires_at + 1.minute) # @stub is nil in this context 
    example.run
    travel_back
  end
```

I can achieve this using `before` and `after` hooks, but I don't want to.

Comment: Have you already considered [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop#user-content-usage)?

Comment: I'm actually already using timecop and considering a switch to safe mode to avoid this need, but still curious about my actual question.